# Find contract address inside the contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging, addresses

How to find contract address inside a contract method? I mean the address of the instance of the contract.

Answer (score 4):

In Solidity, [the `this` object](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#contract-related) is implicitly defined and refers to the current contract. Just like other contract objects, you can cast it to address (eg, `address(this)`) to get its address.